# VSCode Jupyter cannot update kernels automatically

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I'm working on `Ubuntu` by `remoteSSH`, and I updated python kernel in my vitual environment named `nn` form `3.7.9` to `3.8.5`, **however, I still find the old kernel standing in the jupyter kernel list. I want to know how to delete the old kernel name from the kernel list.**

I've replaced `python 3.7.9` and `python3.6.4` with `python 3.8.5`, but the old kernels didn't disappear, I want to delete them manually.

Moreover, I can't select `Python 3.8.5` from the kernel list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have fixed your issue already. But in case anyone else hits this, or a similar issue. VS Code jupyter support looks in the standard jupyter locations for any installed kernelspecs you can see those directories listed here:
https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#data-files

VS Code should pick up anything that Jupyter could pick up. So if you happen to have jupyter installed in a python environment then from the commandline you can run `jupyter kernelspec list` to see a list of all the kernelspecs installed on the system.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and the following might help someone else encountering the issue:

1. Reload VS Code Window by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and selecting `Reload Window`.
2. Reload the Python and Jupyter extensions under the `Extensions` in the Side Bar.
3. Quit and relaunch VS Code.

It seems that VS Code is not that quick to update the interpreter list.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround: in the command palette, search for `Python: Select interpreter`. You then get a dropdown with a little refresh button in the top right corner. After you refresh this list the new interpreter will be listed as a kernel for jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. There are kernel register files in the directorry

```
.local/jupyter/kernels/pythonxxxx
```

I manually delete `python379` and `python364` then everything is totally right.